# Stuck on python list to json object to jquery data chart

Tags: jquery, python, html

I'm having trouble populating the data for a chart on my website. Here is what the data looked like before in query:

```
var data2 = [
            [gd(2012, 1, 1), 7], [gd(2012, 1, 2), 6], [gd(2012, 1, 3), 4], [gd(2012, 1, 4), 8],
            [gd(2012, 1, 5), 9], [gd(2012, 1, 6), 7], [gd(2012, 1, 7), 5], [gd(2012, 1, 8), 4],
            [gd(2012, 1, 9), 7], [gd(2012, 1, 10), 8], [gd(2012, 1, 11), 9], [gd(2012, 1, 12), 6],
            [gd(2012, 1, 13), 4], [gd(2012, 1, 14), 5], [gd(2012, 1, 15), 11], [gd(2012, 1, 16), 8],
            [gd(2012, 1, 17), 8], [gd(2012, 1, 18), 11], [gd(2012, 1, 19), 11], [gd(2012, 1, 20), 6],
            [gd(2012, 1, 21), 6], [gd(2012, 1, 22), 8], [gd(2012, 1, 23), 11], [gd(2012, 1, 24), 13],
            [gd(2012, 1, 25), 7], [gd(2012, 1, 26), 9], [gd(2012, 1, 27), 9], [gd(2012, 1, 28), 8],
            [gd(2012, 1, 29), 5], [gd(2012, 1, 30), 8], [gd(2012, 1, 31), 25]
        ];
```

In my view I have:

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'data': data}), content_type="application/json", status=200)
```

The print from just before the return is:

```
Data: [[1505175303.4467661, 1], [1505175318.294838, 1], [1505175332.872905, 1], [1505175348.181136, 1]]
```

However in the alert(response.data) I get:

```
1505175303.4467661, 1, 1505175318.294838, 1, 1505175332.872905, 1, 1505175348.181136,
```

Why is it converting my array to a string or whatever that is?

I'm doing all this through an ajax call if that changes anything?

Sincerely,

Denis Angell

EDIT:

Here is what the gb function did before:

```
function gd(year, month, day) {
            return new Date(year, month - 1, day).getTime();
        }
```

Comment: Probably you don't have to pass a JSON serialized string into `HttpResponse`, whatever that is, and you are just suppose to pass the unserialized python object: `{'data': data}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`alert(response.data)` does nothing to try and format the data for display, it just calls `toString()` on the object given it, which usually returns a very rudimentary string. Although the structure is lost in presentation, the underlying object will remain intact.

Instead of `alert(response.data)` you could try `console.log(response.data)`, or `alert(response.data[0][0])` to convince yourself that the data structure remains. Or you might iterate over the returned object. Try this in a javascript console:

```
data = [[1505175303.4467661, 1], [1505175318.294838, 1], [1505175332.872905, 1], [1505175348.181136, 1]];

alert(data);
alert(data[0]);
alert(data[0][0]);
console.log(data);

data.forEach(function(element) {
        alert(element[0] + ': ' + element[1]);
    });
```

The first `alert()` should show an apparent loss of structure, however, the subsequent calls should show that the arrays are still present.

---

Also since you're using Django, I think, rather than use `HttpResponse`, use [`JsonResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects):

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

return JsonResponse({'data': data})
```

Comment: Wow thanks alot!! Question, do I need to pass status with the JsonResponse?

Comment: Thanks for explaining that alert is a toString() function. A quick console.log or creating the data in the javascript console would have proved that. It's going to help me use console.log more.